# Automaticaly convert array of structures to structure of arrays in C++

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a struct `Widget` which has several fields inside:

```
struct Widget
{
    Some field1;
    Another second_field;
    ...
};
```

Conceptually I need an array or vector of these Widgets, i.e. `std::vector<Widget>`. But for performance reasons all those fields should be in it's own array, i.e.:

```
struct Widgets
{
    vector<Some> field1;
    vector<Another> second_field;
    ...
};
```

So, given that `Widget` what are possible approaches in C++ to scatter it's fields on several vectors, i.e. to convert array of structures to struct of arrays of fields? Manual definition of some reasonable metadata is OK (inside or outside `Widget`), but solution without additional metadata is preferred.

To clarify, I am looking for a automatic or semi-automatic way of converting `Widget` struct to `Widgets` struct, without manually coding all boilerplate glue.

Comment: I am almost certain you’ll need third-party tools for this. Maybe metaclasses will be able to get this, but I don’t think there's any chance of them being in the language before 2023.

Comment: There is no way to do this automatically. You have to use the hard way.

Answer (score 7):

The core functionality can be implemented using `std::transform` and a few lambda functions.

To get a `std::vector<Some>` from a `std::vector<Widget>`, use:

```
 std::vector<Widget> v1 = { ... };
 std::vector<Some> v2(v1.size());
 std::transform(v1.begin(),
                v1.end(),
                v2.begin(),
                [](Widget const& w) -> Some { return w.field1; });
```

I'll let you figure out the rest.

> I am looking for a automatic or semi-automatic way of converting `Widget` struct to `Widgets` struct, without manually coding all boilerplate glue.

You will have to write some boilerplate code for each member variable of `Widget`. You will be able to reduce the amount of boiler plate code a bit by using a helper function of your own.

E.g.

```
template <typename FieldType, typename Lambda>
void scatter(std::vector<Widget> const& widgets,
             std::vector<FieldType>& fields,
             Lmabda l)
{
   fields.resize(widgets.size());
   std::transform(widgets.begin(), widgets.end(), fields.begin(), l);
}
```

and use it as:

```
 std::vector<Widget> v1 = { ... };
 Widgets w;
 scatter(v1, w.field1, [](Widget const& w) -> Some { return w.field1; });
 scatter(v1, w.second_field, [](Widget const& w) -> Another { return w.second_field; });
 ...
```

Comment: To clarify, main step is to convert `Widget` type to type `Widgets`, as outlined in Q, and that is missing.

Comment: @mechanical, I am assuming that my answer contains enough information for you be able to write the code to flesh out the contents of a `Widgets` object.

Comment: First of all, I need to convert type, not the data. Data itself can be filled into the instance of converted type, without need for runtime transform of data.

Comment: @mechanical You convert *data* of type A to *data* of type B. "Converting types" doesn't look like a well defined operation.

Comment: @n.m. Converting (or transforming) types is well-defined operation in C++. This is exactly what [metafuncitons do](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction.html).

Comment: @mechanical, you don't have an answer to your problem yet you claim to understand what's possible and a well defined operation in C++. A little humility will be helpful.

Comment: @RSahu Please ignore this topic if you have nothing to add.

Comment: @mechanical Didn't realise you are talking about metaprogramming, sorry. There's no metafunction that would convert a user-defined class type to a list of types of its fields or anything like that. Not before reflection is added to C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the `[]` operator so that the members adjacent in memory (as the second example) but you can behave as if there was a vector of structs:

```
struct Widget { 
  Some &field1; Another &second_field; ... 
  Widget(Some &f1, Another &f2 ...) : field1(f1), second_field(f2) ... {};
};

struct Widgets
{
   Widgets(int size) : field1(size), second_field(size) ... {};
   vector<Some> field1;
   vector<Another> second_field;
   Widget &operator[](int i) { return { field1[i], second_field[i] }; }
};
```

Now you can treat Widgets as a regular array of structs:

```
Widgets w(5);
w[3].field1 = Some(42);
```

The compiler is good at optimizing functions but not the way you store data. Thus you may expect `operator[]` not to initialize a new struct if you want to extract an element or similar, while the data are still vectorized.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get that `operator[]` and related boilerplate to be generated automatically, or at least semi-automatically. So I do not need to redo same in each similar case.

Comment: @n.m. The performance gain is because of the struct of arrays vs. array of structs. The whole purpose of the overloading is to have an interface of array of structs, while still allowing code to be vectorized nicely (C# does it automatically btw).

Comment: I am looking for a way to get this overload (semi or fully)automatically.

Comment: @mechanical I could maybe prepare you a variadic template version but I'm going to sleep atm. Maybe tomorrow :)